# emulating iPhone video player behaviour

Tags: http, youtube, testing

I need to debug a networking application which handles video downloaded by iPhone from Youtube. iPhone downloads chunks of video by requesting each time a different file range (by adding Content-Range in HTTP GET header) while PC applications usually request a whole file.

Are there any PC application (preferably Linux, but Windows is also OK) which I can use to emulate this iPhone browser's behavior?

(Note that simply seeking the video in browser does produce HTTP content-range request, it simply gives URL with time position.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot Linux comes with two powerful download utilities wget and curl. The latter can do exactly what I need - download file byte ranges over persistent HTTP connection.